# Problem with video fullscreen on safari mobile

Tags: ios, reactjs, fullscreen, react-player

We are using react-player ,but with custom controllers. We installed react-fullscreen for the fullscreen functionality but it didn't work on safari(mobile). All the internet say that Fullscreen API , that is used in react-fullscreen component, is not supported on IOS.Give us a solution